# Change permissions on shared memory after creation on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, shared-memory

I have an issue where I need to have shared memory created with world read/write permissions and then at some point later change that memory to be only accessible by a single group. Is it possible to do this or do I need to tear down the memory segment and create a new one with the proper user permissions?

Comment: possible of course

Comment: _"...To set the security descriptor of a file-mapping object, call the SetNamedSecurityInfo or SetSecurityInfo function...."_ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/file-mapping-security-and-access-rights